# When I running as an exported jar, I get a FileNotFound exeption

Tags: java, jar, ide, filenotfoundexception

I am creating a program that runs some sound files. When I run it in my IDE (Eclipse) it runs fine, but when running from a jar the file's path seems to have changed. The project's path is:

```
MyProject: 
           src (in build path):
                package:
                       AudioFile.java
                       SoundEffectManager.java
           assets (in build path):
                 sounds:
                      soundfile.wav
```

and the code for AudioFile.java that reads the file:

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;

public class AudioFile implements LineListener {
    private File audioFile;
    private boolean paused = false;
    private AudioInputStream ais;
    private AudioFormat format;
    private DataLine.Info info;
    private Clip clip;
    private volatile boolean playing;

   // Constructor
    public AudioFile(String fileName) {
        try {
        audioFile = new File(fileName);
        ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);
        format = ais.getFormat();
        info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
        clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.addLineListener(this);
        clip.open(ais);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    // Play Pause and other helpers
    public void play() {
        clip.start();
        playing = true;
    }

    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return playing;
    }

    public void stop() {
        clip.stop();
        clip.flush();
        clip.setFramePosition(0);
        playing = false;
    }

    public void pause() {
        if (!paused) {
        paused = true;
        clip.stop();
        }
    }
    public void resume() {
        if (paused) {
            clip.start();
            paused = false;
        } 
    }
    @Override
    public void update(LineEvent event) {
        if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.START && !paused) {
            playing = true;
        }
        else if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP && !paused) {
            clip.stop();
            clip.flush();
            clip.setFramePosition(0);
            playing = false;
            paused = false;
        }

    } 

}
```

SoundEffectManager.java's code that creates an AudioFile (helpers and imports omitted)

```
public class SoundEffectManager implements Runnable {
    private ArrayList<AudioFile> soundList;
    private volatile boolean running;
    public volatile ArrayList<AudioFile> playingSounds;
    public SoundEffectManager(String... sounds) {
        soundList = new ArrayList<AudioFile>();
        for(String sound : sounds) {
            soundList.add(new AudioFile("./assets/sounds/" + sound + ".wav"));
        }

    }
}
```

When the SoundEffectManager constructor is called it is called with the arguments: "soundfile"

This code works in the IDE but not in a runnable jar due to a java.io.FileNotFound exception.
The File path for the jar is:

```
jarfile.jar:
            package:
                       AudioFile.class
                       SoundEffectManager.class

            META-INF:
                      MANIFEST.MF
            sounds:
               soundfile.wav
```

Thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your sound files in the resource folder. Then you can get the path through the classloader. This should work in your ide and jar file.

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("soundfile").getPath()
```